# Brownian motion and elliptic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo

Recently I read about a Monte Carlo method useful to solve the Dirichlet problem
$$(1)\left\{\begin{matrix}
\Delta u(x) = 0,\quad x\in D\\ 
u(x) = f(x),\quad x\in\partial D
\end{matrix}\right.$$
All of the method is based in the fact
$$u(x) = \mathbb{E}(B_\tau)\quad (x\in D)$$
where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion starting in $x$ and $\tau=\inf\{t\geq0:B(t)\not\in D\}$.

My question is, do exist more general methods of this style for solving PDE? In particular, I am interested in methods for solving elliptic PDE based in a particular stochastic process, but similar things are also of my interest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

There is the [Feynman-Kac formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula) that represents the solution of a rather broad class of PDEs (heat equation, advection-diffusion equation, Black-Scholes PDE in log form are included) as the expectation over a random walk.

In particular, for elliptic PDEs, [look here](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07362994.2015.1050559?journalCode=lsaa20).

Comment: What’s the application you are thinking of?

Comment: I have to do a "proyect" in a course of stochastic simulation. With "proyect" I mean a ~2 week homework in wich I choose a topic and run variuous sthocastics simulations.

Comment: You may want to check out Stanley Farlow's PDE book, there's exclusively a chapter on Monte Carlo simulations for PDE in which you can run random walks from a lattice to generate an approximation to Elliptic PDE. It's pretty easy to code as well!

Comment: I will chek it, thanks! Anyone knows if there exists a general algorithm for solving a general elliptic pde? or at least a wider class of elliptic pde beyond heat and laplace equations?

Comment: There are finite difference schemes for pretty much any of them.  Anyway, which other ones are you thinking of?